# Setting reply-to address in Domino/Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

As background, I'm a very reluctant Domino "admin" and know very little about settings on the server.

I have a mail-in database which is using the ID of the admin who set it up as the from/reply address.  Obviously he'd prefer that replies go back to the mail-in database.  Where can I set the reply-to address or the from address to something else?

**Clarification** (probably the first of many):  The mailbox receives mail (it's the webmaster@ourcompany address).  A couple of people monitor the mailbox and send replies if any are warranted.  We don't want the replies coming from any individual's address - just have them come from webmaster.  Instead, they appear to come from [BOFH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_Operator_From_Hell)@ourcompany.com.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend converting the design of the mail-in database from the standard mail template to the DominoTeamMailbox template available at OpenNTF:

http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/DominoTeamMailbox

You can manually set the from/reply-to addresses in the database configuration. We use it for all of our mail-in databases (as well as our customers').

Comment: This is looking promising.  I can't find any information about whether it's been updated for Domino 8.  Have you tried it under 8 yet?

Comment: We use it under both 7 and 8 with no problems. It's documented as working for Domino 7 or later, FYI.

Comment: I use this on several client sites, some running 8.5.3 and it works no problem.  The look and feel is not the 8 template, but functionality wise, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you make mail-in-database and give it hierrarcical name like info/mail and put it as owner of the mail box, the reply address will be always the internet address of the mail-in-database. (it will show sent by someone though).

Answer (score 0):

I take it he's got an agent within that database that is sending out email when a new message comes into the database?  Otherwise, why would you be concerned with replies for a database that *receives* email?

If my assumptions are correct, the easiest solution is to sign that agent with another ID.  You might create a generic ID for this purpose and name it the same or similar to your Mail In Database name.

Depending on how the emails are being generated, you could edit the code in the agent to set the reply address.  For example, if the agent is using the @MailSend function, there's a parameter for reply-to name.  Otherwise, the ID that signed the agent will be used for the from and reply addresses.